# Pull to refresh for horizontal listview in android

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh, horizontallist

I have implemented pull to refresh in listview through [this](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView) link . But i need to integrate the same think in horizontal list view.Any samples/ideas should be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will need swipe to refresh thing for recyclerview with horizontal layout manager. I've implement it: https://github.com/ashakirov/Horizontal-SwipeRefreshLayout

[image]